# get detailsView values in Edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

i have a DetailsView bound to a `Datatable` 
I managed to use my own Edit, Update, Cancel buttons
the problem I'm facing is I can't get the value of DetailsView cells when updating
here is my code to get values in `EditMode`

```
        protected void BP_Info_View_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BP_Info_View.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {
            //get the value of fields from detailsView
            string cardname = BP_Info_View.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string address = BP_Info_View.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string zipcode = BP_Info_View.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string mailaddress = BP_Info_View.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string mailzipcode = BP_Info_View.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string phone1 = BP_Info_View.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string phone2 = BP_Info_View.Rows[6].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string cell = BP_Info_View.Rows[7].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string fax = BP_Info_View.Rows[8].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string cntprsn = BP_Info_View.Rows[9].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            string city = BP_Info_View.Rows[10].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            //update here
        }
    }
```

update works perfect If I assign other data to my variables.
what is missing of my code to retrieve values from DetailsView in editMode?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox tx = BP_Info_View.Rows[7].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
```

should use TextBox, in EditMode it's textbox not string!